# Remote access to jupyter notebook running in docker container on WSL 2

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, wsl-2

Is there a general way for remote access to jupyter notebook running in a docker container on the WSL 2?

FYI, WSL 2 (Ubuntu 20.04) is installed following the instructions below:

- https://ubuntu.com/blog/getting-started-with-cuda-on-ubuntu-on-wsl-2
- https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/announcing-cuda-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2/

Comment: does `--no-browser` not work ? For ex, jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=xxxx in the Container (after opening the container ports), and ssh from local machine to the container ? (For ex, https://amber-md.github.io/pytraj/latest/tutorials/remote_jupyter_notebook)

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I was worrying about how to connect to the linux server via Windows using ssh because  Windows does not have direct access to the jupyter notebook server on WSL-2. I am not sure if the link you gave deals with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem but I wasn't using Docker.

I couldn't connect to the server on WSL from the local or remote network.

Apparently, WSL 2 uses a virtual network adapter that has its own IP address. It also changes the IP address every time the server is restarted. I had to write a script that forwarded the network traffic from the virtual machine to the host computer. This allowed me to access the server using the private IP address of the host computer.

I wrote an article about how to do it to make it easier for everyone:

[How to Set Up the Jupyter Notebook Server in WSL2](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-set-up-a-jupiter-notebook-server-and-access-it-from-a-local-or-remote-network-on-windows-d335c5ba490d)

Comment: I had a similar question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67756025/access-wsl2-jupyter-notebook-remotely (of course since then wsl virtual network has changed and your post isn't available anymore) so can you give an update on how to do it?

Comment: Hi-there @Moe. The link has been updated. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: well its not free to look at :(

Comment: Just use incognito mode =]